# why IdentityHashMap uses linear probing for collision resolution

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, collections, dictionary

As we know in java collections framework every class in **`Map`** uses Chaining for collision resolution but **`IdentityHashMap`** uses linear probing for the same.

If you see the java docs, it has mentioned:

> For many JRE implementations and operation mixes, this class will
>   yield better performance than HashMap (which uses chaining rather than
>   linear-probing).

My questions are:

- why the implementors have used **liner probing** only for `IdentityHashMap` instead of all the `Map` implementations if performance is better in **linear probing**
- Why there is a performance gain in **linear Probing** then **chaining**.

Tanks.

Comment: The answer is on the javadoc. Performance. Looks like this special implementation of `Map` is designed for those rare case where object identity is sufficiant and performance a criteria.

Comment: @ Andreas_D How this helps in performance can you tell me?

Comment: @Andreas_D: That is *not* answering the question because it begets an obvious next question: *why* is the performance better in this case, because it is *not* always true that linear probing performs better than chaining. What holds the Earth up? An tortoise! [*Well, then what is holding the tortoise up?*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turtles_all_the_way_down)

Comment: @Jason then he should ask THAT question which *might* make more sense and can't be answered by just looking at the documentation which comes with the class. He asked for the **reason behind the approach** and the programmers told us their reasons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may shed some light (taken from the [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html) website):

> Implementation note: This is a simple linear-probe hash table, as described for example in texts by Sedgewick and Knuth. The array alternates holding keys and values. (This has better locality for large tables than does using separate arrays.) **For many JRE implementations and operation mixes, this class will yield better performance than HashMap** (which uses chaining rather than linear-probing).

Although chaining may be better for most implementations, it is not so for every implementation.

**EDIT** Also found this, perhaps it's less trivial (taken from [here](http://codeidol.com/java/javagenerics/Maps/Implementing-Map/)):

> The motivation for using probing is that it is somewhat faster than following a linked list, but that is only true when a reference to the value can be placed directly in the array. That isn't practical for all other hash-based collections, because they store the hash code as well as the value. This is for reasons of efficiency: a get operation must check whether it has found the right key, and since equality is an expensive operation, it makes sense to check first whether it even has the right hash code. Of course, this reasoning doesn't apply to `IdentityHashMap`, which checks object identity rather than object equality.

As background/clarification, an `IdentityHashMap` differs from an ordinary `HashMap` in that two keys are considered equal only if they are physically the same object: identity, rather than equals, is used for key comparison.

**EDIT:** discussion that helps in finding the answer (from comments below):

Trying:

> but that is only true when a reference to the value can be placed directly in the array. That isn't practical for all other hash-based collections, because they store the hash code as well as the value. I have a doubt that why can't hashMap put the key, value and hash code in the array and use linear probing if linked list traversal is more costly then direct array?

wlyles:

> likely because of space usage. That would take up more data in each slot. And I should point out that, while traversal is less costly for linear probing, the total find operation could be more costly (and less predictable) because linear probing is often plagued by clustering, where many keys have the same hash value. As said by @delnan in another comment, For example, if keys 1..20 hash to consecutive slots, and the 21st hashes to the same slot as the 1st, lookup for it (or for a not-present key that hashes to the 1st slot) needs 20 probes. Using a list would take fewer probes. For further clarification: because of the way that IdentityHashMap compares key values, the chance of collisions is very small. Thus, the main weakness of linear probing - collisions that lead to clumping - is largely avoided, making it more desirable in this implementation.
>
> For further clarification: because of the way that IdentityHashMap compares key values, the chance of collisions is very small. Thus, the main weakness of linear probing - collisions that lead to clumping - is largely avoided, making it more desirable in this implementation

Comment: All that says is that the class will sometimes yield better performance; it doesn't say *why* linear-probing vs. chaining. Presumably the answer *is* "better performance" but that just begets the obvious next question: *why* is the performance better in the expected usage for `IdentityHashMap`, because that is not always the case when one picks linear-probing over various chaining methods.

Comment: @wlyles I liked the answer specially after edit. `but that is only true when a reference to the value can be placed directly in the array. That isn't practical for all other hash-based collections, because they store the hash code as well as the value.` I have a doubt that why can't hashMap put the `key, value and hash code` in the array and use linear probing if linked list traversal is more costly then direct array? Thanks!!!

Comment: @Trying likely because of space usage. That would take up more data in each slot. And I should point out that, while *traversal* is less costly for linear probing, the *total* find operation could be more costly (and less predictable) because linear probing is often plagued by clustering, where many keys have the same hash value. As said by @delnan in another comment, `For example, if keys 1..20 hash to consecutive slots, and the 21st hashes to the same slot as the 1st, lookup for it (or for a not-present key that hashes to the 1st slot) needs 20 probes.` Using a list would take fewer probes

Comment: For further clarification: because of the way that `IdentityHashMap` compares key values, the chance of collisions is very small. Thus, the main weakness of linear probing - collisions that lead to clumping - is largely avoided, making it more desirable in this implementation.

Answer (score 11):

When you build an identity hash map, there is no chance of finding two instances that are equal to each other yet are not the same object. It also uses [`System.identityHashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode(java.lang.Object)), which has a chance of collisions that is known upfront to the designers of `IdentityHashMap`, and is known to be very small. Under these "laboratory" conditions, linear probing appears to be a better choice in terms of performance.

I suspect that the reason the designers of the class library used chaining rather than linear probing in "regular" hash maps is their desire to maintain decent performance even when hash functions are suboptimal.

Comment: +1 Also: "*I suspect that the reason the designers of the class library used chaining rather than linear probing in "regular" hash maps is their desire to maintain decent performance even when hash functions are suboptimal.*" Agree.

Comment: That's a good reason to use open addressing (or more generally deviate from whatever other hash maps do to alleviate collisions). However, it doesn't sound like a good reason to use linear probing specifically: Linear probing is very vulnerable to clustering (many keys hashing to consecutive/nearby slots). For example, if keys 1..20 hash to consecutive slots, and the 21st hashes to the same slot as the 1st, lookup for it (or for a not-present key that hashes to the 1st slot) needs 20 probes. And AFAIK on typical JVMs clustering is likely (the hash is the address, allocation is linear).

Comment: Not exactly: http://blogs.tedneward.com/2008/07/16/ObjecthashCode+Implementation.aspx

Answer (score -2):

[From Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html):

> Implementation note: This is a simple linear-probe hash table, as described for example in texts by Sedgewick and Knuth. The array alternates holding keys and values. **(This has better locality for large tables than does using separate arrays.)** For many JRE implementations and operation mixes, this class will yield better performance than HashMap (which uses chaining rather than linear-probing).

The Reason is *that this class` will yield better performance than HashMap.*

Comment: This does not answer the *why* of linear-probing vs. chaining.

Comment: `For many JRE implementations and operation mixes, this class will yield better performance than HashMap` This is not a real answer, and this answer is trivial at best, since it is just a link.

Comment: @Jason of course it does: better performance compared to HashMap. Just RTFM.

Comment: I believe `This has better locality for large tables than does using separate arrays` is the meat of this answer

Comment: @JanDvorak no, that line is for not using two arrays. The edit made the answer even more wrong now.

Comment: @Jason I hope the small example given in docs is making some sense.

Comment: The statement you bolded has to do with how the keys and values are stored and has nothing to do with the linear probing. The locality refers to when you pull a key, the value is right next to it.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Sorry, [try again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195733/reason-behind-using-linear-probing-in-identityhashmap#comment24904934_17195864). Also, we don't speak like that here ("RTFM").

Comment: @Jason: Chain-bucket tables are less susceptible than linear-probe tables to having their performance sunk by non-uniform hash functions.  Suppose a hash function only yields values 0-255 for things of some type, and one puts 1,000 of them into a table.  Looking for something that's not in the table would likely require inspecting an average of about 4-10 items in a chain-bucket table, but would often require inspecting 750+ items in a linear-probe table.  Identity hash values are basically guaranteed to be at least somewhat-decently distributed, and thus avoid that problem.