# check if Hashtable is full java

Tags: java, hashtable, capacity

As stated in the topic, how can I check if Hashtable is full (if one could do that at all)?

Having:

```
HashMap<Integer, Person> p = new HashMap <>();
```

I imagine one needs to use e.g.

```
if (p.size()>p "capacity"==true)
```

I found somewhere that hashtables are created with a default size 11 and their capacity is automatically increased if needed... So in the end, can Hashtable ever be full?

Comment: Hashtables don't get full. Increasing their "capacity" is used to make them faster to access, but it is not a real limit on how much they can hold.

Comment: @khelwood right except last part... check sleiman answer ;)

Comment: @JordiCastilla No; I'm right including the last part.

Comment: @khelwood really? have you readed? first of all, **it must be a real limit**, if not limited by object itself (*as is explained in sleiman answer*), at least computer memory will define this limit... so IMO last part of your comment is not accurated. `:)`

Comment: @JordiCastilla 1) The "capacity" does not limit how much a hashtable can hold, only the number of buckets they have. 2) Nothing in my comment indicates that computers don't run out of memory, only that hashtables don't get full.

Comment: You are mixing up `HashMap` and `Hashtable`. The latter has an initial capacity of `11`, but `HashMap`’s initial capacity is `16`. In either case, the capacity will be increased, even before containing that much elements, as the default load factor is `0.75`, so it will be increased on the 13th, resp. 9th insertion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `Hashtable`s are created with a default size 11

That is not the size of `HashTable`, it's the number of hash buckets it has.

Obviously, a table with 11 hash buckets can hold *less* than 11 items. Perhaps less obviously, a table with 11 buckets may also hold *more* than 11 items, depending on [*collision resolution*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution) in use.

> can `Hashtable` ever be full?

This depends on the implementation. Hash tables that use separate chaining, such as Java's `HashMap`, cannot get full, even if all their buckets are exhausted, because we can continue adding items to individual chains of each bucket. However, using too few hash buckets leads to significant loss of performance.

On the other hand, hash tables with linear probing, such as Java's `IdentityHashMap` (which is not, strictly speaking, a valid hash-based container), can get full when you run out of buckets.

Comment: @Holger [Here is a Q&A dedicated to this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17195733/335858).

Comment: @Holger it does use linear probing to resolve collisions, check the source code. I thought Holger knows everything  :)

Comment: @Sleiman Jneidi: That’s describing the *collision resolution*. It’s still hashing in the first place. So I object the statement that this is “not, strictly speaking, a valid hash-based container”.

Comment: Well yeah, it uses hashing, but for collision resolution it uses probing rather than chaining. "not, strictly speaking, a valid hash-based container” is not a very accurate statement. I believe

Comment: Well Java 8’s `HashMap` implementation switches from chaining to a tree in certain cases. The way, collisions are handled, is not carved in stone…

Comment: @Holger Here is why I say that `IdentityHashMap` is not a valid hash-based container: ["While this class implements the Map interface, it intentionally violates Map's general contract, which mandates the use of the equals method when comparing objects."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/IdentityHashMap.html)

Comment: But this has nothing to do with the linear probing, so it’s a misleading statement. Especially as you said “*valid hash-based container*” which in no way indicates that you are talking about the contract of Java’s `Map` interface, rather than hash-based containers in general.

Comment: But besides the validity statement, the entire sentence is likely to create confusion at the reader as Java’s `IdentityHashMap` can’t get full as it will increase its capacity when needed. That applies to all of Java’s hash maps, when the size reaches capacity×load factor, the capacity is increased and the load factor is *at most* `1`, so inserting more elements than the number of buckets *guarantees* a capacity increase. The default load factor is `0.75`.

Comment: @Holger My point was that hash containers that use linear probing can and will get full once you reach their maximum bucket capacity (which is, admittedly, very high, so one is more likely to run out of memory before that happens). Hash containers with separate chaining do not have such theoretical upper limit, because they continue allocating nodes into bucket chains even when their bucket array is at its max capacity.

Comment: Indeed, though reaching a size which doesn’t fit into the `int` value range could cause problems with Java `Map`s in general. I’m currently trying to max it out and stumbled upon the fact that `IdentityHashMap` uses a flat array whereas `HashMap` uses an array of `Entry` instances which consume far more memory than a simple array slot. Currently, I’m shortly above `1<<28` elements in the `HashMap` and experiencing a system slowdown. I suppose, I need a different machine to find the practical limit. With this machine, both maps won’t hit their limit…

Answer (score 4):

HashMap has a maximum capacity of 1073741824 elements, theoretically

from the source code of `HashMap`

```
/**
 * The maximum capacity, used if a higher value is implicitly specified
 * by either of the constructors with arguments.
 * MUST be a power of two <= 1<<30.
 */
static final int MAXIMUM_CAPACITY = 1 << 30;
```

But here it is limited to the number of elements a managed array (used for the backing array) can hold in Java. The JVM might fail with Out of Memory Error when you try to allocate big arrays.

That said, if the HashMap is really awful ( too many populated buckets), the HashMap wouldn't need to allocate or reallocate big arrays because key are not well distributed, it would be allocating more `TreeMap` or `Lists` nodes depending on the nature of the keys.

Comment: This is not a "capacity" as most people would understand it. It's the number to which the `capacity` constructor argument will be capped, but it's not a maximum number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

The `capacity` argument provides a hint to the implementation of an *initial* size for its internal table. This can save a few internal resizes.

However, a HashMap won't stop accepting `put()`s unless the JVM encounters an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Under the covers, a hashmap is an array. Hashes are used as array indices. Each array element is a reference to a linked list of `Entry` objects. The linked list can be arbitrarily long.